# Black Background When Click On EditText

Tags: android

![enter image description here][1]In android we Create a RetailerRegistration form when softkeyboard open then bottom field are hide so we use on scrollview but when we use scrollview and click on edittext then softkeyboard open and whole screen turn on black how to resolve it please suggest

`<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:minHeight="40px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1.0dp"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
            <TextView
                android:text="Retailer Name"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textViewretailerName"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                style="@style/TextView_Small" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editTextretailername"
                android:gravity="left"
                style="@style/EditText_Small2"
                android:maxLength="30"
                android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
                android:editable="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout18">
            <TextView
                android:text="Mobile No."
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textViewretailerMobileNo"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                style="@style/TextView_Small" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editTextretailerMobile"
                android:gravity="left"
                style="@style/EditText_Small2"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:editable="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">
            <TextView
                android:text="Address"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textViewretailerAddress"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                style="@style/TextView_Small" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editTextretaileraddress1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:minLines="2"
                style="@style/EditText_Small2"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
                android:editable="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">
            <TextView
                android:text=""
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textViewretailerAddress1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                style="@style/TextView_Small" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editTextretaileraddress2"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:minLines="2"
                style="@style/EditText_Small2"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
                android:editable="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4">
            <TextView
                android:text="PinCode"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textViewretailerzipcode"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                style="@style/TextView_Small" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editTextretailerzipcode"
                android:gravity="left"
                style="@style/EditText_Small2"
                android:maxLength="6"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:editable="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout5">
            <TextView
                android:text="Town"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textViewretailercity"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                style="@style/TextView_Small" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editTextretailercity"
                android:gravity="left"
                style="@style/EditText_Small2"
                android:maxLength="50"
                android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
                android:editable="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout6">
            <TextView
                android:text="District"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textViewretailerdistrict"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                style="@style/TextView_Small" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editTextretailerdistrict"
                android:gravity="left"
                style="@style/EditText_Small2"
                android:maxLength="50"
                android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
                android:editable="false" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout7">
            <TextView
                android:text="State"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textViewretailerstate"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                style="@style/TextView_Small" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editTextretailerState"
                android:gravity="left"
                style="@style/EditText_Small2"
                android:maxLength="50"
                android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
                android:editable="false" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>`

try this Link for screenshot
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/13vOw.png

Comment: Will you be more specific. Because i didn't get any blank screen on above snippet.

Comment: put screenshots if possible

Comment: when we upload screenShots give error atleast 10 reputation if u share emailid then we sent please

Comment: upload it in any cloud like dropbox and provide public link

Comment: Scrreen Shot add when click on edittext then show blackscreen

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but it works fine for me.
Make your main Layout Relative "Relative Layout".
and Inside this Layout add your "Scroll View".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.